# This happens all the times when I create a new project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time when I create new android project I have to click **use JDK from project structure**.
Is there anyway to fix this help me with this problem

[image]

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46358454/11002756

Comment: From  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32654016/11002756)